# adding a class after email is validated using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

I'm trying to use jQuery for email validation in a form field

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email = new RegExp("[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$");
    var value = $("#email_address").val();

    $("#email_address").on("keypress", function() {
        if(email.test(value)) {
            $("#email_address").parent().addClass("has-success");
        }
    });
});
```

However, the `has-success` class doesn't get added. I've tried each line of code individually in the console and they all seem to be doing/pointing to the right thing. It's when it's all put together that it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You load the value on jQuery's DOM ready and never load it again.

You need to test the *current* value, not the one that's there when the DOM is ready, roughly:

```
$("#email_address").on("keypress", function() {
    if(email.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#email_address").parent().addClass("has-success");
    }
});
```

Unrelated, but personally I'd wrap up the email test in a function so instead of saying `email.test(xxx)` you could read it more naturally like `validEmail(xxx)` etc.